Browser not using web assembly for Flutter web app
I am building a flutter web app (using flutter 3.22 and Flame Engine). I am building the app with the --wasm flag.
But neither Chrome nor Edge is uses the wasm modules and instead falls back to js.

This is my source code: https://github.com/MG-LSJ/visual_graphs

Finally I found an answer on Flutter docs on WASM
https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/wasm#serve-the-built-output-with-an-http-server

Flutter web applications won't run with WebAssembly unless the server
is configured to send specific HTTP headers.

